# Error_code: 2005 - Mysql Operator - Error connecting to master

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, mysql-cluster, kubernetes-operator

In a cluster of 3 nodes, node-1 crashes with the following error in the Mysql container logs:

```
2020-05-19T17:40:00.273585Z 12 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'sys_replication@mysql-vrit5nyrtlgbnrbln45tgtrgb-mysql-0.mysql.vrit5nyrtlgbnr' - retry-time: 10  retries: 32, Error_code: 2005
```

The master node, node-0, is 4/4 and working fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was having a long server name. The full DNS name of the node-0 (plus the namespace's name) was:

```
mysql-vrit5nyrtlgbnrbln45tgtrgb-mysql-0.mysql.vrit5nyrtlgbnrbln45tgtrgb
```

which was more than 60 characters. Therefore, it was being truncated to `mysql-vrit5nyrtlgbnrbln45tgtrgb-mysql-0.mysql.vrit5nyrtlgbnr`, which was an invalid server name, resulting in the error message.